High frequency noise increasing by current drawn
There are a lot of noise related questions here. Mine may be somewhat different.
I'm using a 24V 2A SMPS power supply bought from market.  I've used more than 20 of them.
Some have noiseless output voltage through the whole current range.
Some have lots of noise as in the attached picture. Increasing current drawn increases the noise.
In my circuit this voltage is used to drive stepper motors, a linear regulator is used for cpu.
There is no problem driving stepper motors since it is using only the DC component of the power and the stepper motor itself is already an inductive load filtering out the noise.
The USB connection to the computer is very susceptible to that noise. When the motors start, the USB channel immediately blocks. Most of the time, restarting the PC is required.
High quality USB cable and transient suppressors didn't solve the issue.
The schematic of the SMPS is also attached. It seems the most critical part for this noise is the capacitor in the flyback circuit. I measured it -  it is correct.
Does anyone have idea where to look to identify the origin of this noise?
Note: Actually I don't have to repair the SMPS I bought. I just may discard it, but I'm curious about what is going on. It may be helpful for my future designs.
Oscilloscope screenshots

Enlarged noise image

Schematic

MOSFET drain
I want to share the screenshot of the drain voltage of mosfet, is is highly irregular (as expected). Is this irregular shape explain the high noise that even break usb communication ? Normally I won't expect.


Is it common or differential mode noise? If you aren't sure, then can you show how you are probing it (e.g. photo of power supply, leads, load, probe and oscilloscope)?

also, can you tell us more about the output capacitors from your schematic?

If is differential mode noise, i.e. instantaneous voltage with respect to gnd is changing. No problem at measurement, when one to one equal is tested it is functioning excellent. Then I measured the drain of the mosfet, saw that there is a fundamental half wave rectified voltage, which shouldn't be so. Finally saw that the 47uF capacitor after the bridge was defect. Just now I don't hane a replacement, I hope when replaced it will function as required.

@Kiymik - Hi, You posted something as an answer, but it wasn't the answer to your question so it has been deleted. Did you mean to add it into your question as new information? Or did you mean it to be a response to a specific comment? Or something else? || Whatever you intended, since you asked the question, please do not use the text box below labeled "Your Answer" unless you are posting a new full & final answer to your own question, which doesn't just confirm another answer. TY

@Kiymik I just added your non-answer "answer" post's content to your question, it seemed relevant. But please heed what SamGibson asks you to do in the comment above.

Regarding USB, it should be immune to most noise sources -- check that the cable shields are well mated on both ends, and that high quality cables have been used, with good shield integrity between connectors. Cheap, poorly-made cables abound, and connectors can mate poorly, or wear over time and develop poor connections.

Further checks, I put a small (2.2uF) capacitor instead of 47uF, got noiseless dc voltage at output for whole current range. Only difference is at currents above 0.5A some ripple occured, it is already expected. All noise was because instantaneous currents at high frequency pwm was drawn directly from line, causing a lot of conducted emission, probably this was the reason usb failed. Thanks for your comments.

The y-capacitor is missing?
Rapid voltage changes in the transformer and it's parasitic capacitance create some current that needs a way back.

